# Finding Database Entries via Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have two resources, `project` and `collective`, with a `has_many through` relation via my join table `projectships`. My `project` resource of course has `id` as a column but also has `unique_id` as a column (its important). The `projectships` table has standard columns `id`, `project_id`, and `collective_id` except that `project`'s `unique_id` is used for the join table's `project_id`.

What I want to do is pull all of the projects relating to a specific collective. Normally I would just use:

```
@projects = @collective.projects
```

but this doesn't work since my `project_id` column is populated by `unique_id` instead of project's `id`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!